# Display Random Product Link

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need PHP-code for WordPress (Woocommerce) to display **random product link**.

For example, I have Product1 and want to display on this page (in description of my product):

"See also other products: [Product2 - link] and [Product3 - link]"

Don't know how, I just need php code to insert it in post/pages/products and everywhere I want on my site.

I'm not a coder and I found this code, for example, to display page title with link, but it's  not what I need

```
<?php
echo '<a href="'.get_permalink($product_id).'">'.get_the_title($product_id).'</a>';
?>
```

But **how to get random product**, don't know, thanks for help.

Comment: You should search for this at wordpress.stackexchange.com or the wordpress foruns, maybe it's easier to find an answer there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 $args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => 1,
    'orderby'          => 'rand',
    'post_type'        => 'product' ); 

$random_products = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $random_products as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
<?php endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Answer (score 0):

The Perfect solution for outputting a single random product which can be achieved using the following code.

```
<?php
$post_array=array();
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => 12
        );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
            array_push($post_array,get_the_ID());
        endwhile;
        $random_key = array_rand($post_array, 1);
        echo '<a href="'.get_permalink($post_array[$random_key]).'">'.get_the_title($post_array[$random_key]).'</a>';
    } else {
        echo __( 'No products found' );
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Have tested the same for you. It worked. Lemme Know if the same worked for you too.

Comment: Works great! Many thanks! But when I reload page - a product changes. Is it a way to display random products once without changes?

Comment: That's why it's called random. On every access to the page a random product will be generated and displayed. If we keep it constant it won't be called as  random. If your still want it to be kept. You can set it in user session so that each session of user will have a random product same throughout the session. I hope this clears your doubt. And solves you request